# Absolute value of integral, is my understanding correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Let $a\geq 0$
Find the area that is bounded by: $x = 1$ , $x = a$ and $y = 0$ and $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$\
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$$

We do not know if $a$ may be less than $1$. That's why I would take the integral in absolute values.
By that I mean:

$$|\int_1^a \frac{1}{x} dx| = |\ln{a} - \ln{1}| = |\ln{a}|\implies |\int_1^a \frac{1}{x} dx| = |\ln{a}|$$

Now I also have a more general question about using the absolute value outside the integral.

For example, does this hold?: $$|\int_1^a \frac{1}{x} dx| = |\int_a^1 \frac{1}{x} dx|$$

Or was I just lucky for this to work in my case (of course if my solution is correct)

Answer (score 1):

That identity is true in general for definite integrals (provided everything is well-defined). In general, if $a < b$ and $f$ is integrable over $[a,b]$, then

$$\int_b^a f(x)\,dx = -\int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$

Note the changed order on the limits of integration. Thus by taking absolute values, you have your proposed identity.

As for the problem at hand, it is fine. I might do a $\pm$ on the answer myself (rather probably just say "if $a < 1$, then (answer), else if $a > 1$, then (answer)"), but if you explain in words a bit on your actual answer, it should be clear what your intent is.